# Stripe Webhook Controller Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, stripe-payments

I have the following:

```
public class StripeController : Controller
{

    private readonly UserService _userService;

    public StripeController(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult StripeWebook()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/stripewebhook")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var json = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        var stripeEvent = StripeEventUtility.ParseEvent(json);

        switch (stripeEvent.Type)
        {
            case StripeEvents.ChargeRefunded:  // all of the types available are listed in StripeEvents
                var stripeCharge = Stripe.Mapper<StripeCharge>.MapFromJson(stripeEvent.Data.Object.ToString());
                break;
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }


}
```

And requests from stripe generate an error:

> The controller for path '/api/stripewebhook' was not found or does not implement IController

Any idea why this is happening when I test from the stripe portal?

Comment: Shouldn't it inherit `ApiController` instead of `Controller`?

Comment: @Gusman https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/issues/818#issuecomment-293068650

Comment: What do you mean with that? If this is WebAPI 2 it must inherit from ApiController: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Or is the COntroller class some class from the Stripe framework?

Comment: @Gusman did you see the link?  That's how the author recommended implementing a webhook receiver, and that's how I'm doing it above, and it's not working.  WebApi requests don't have access to InputStream anyways as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, and that's incorrect for WebApi 2, the author even told he did not remember how to do it because he doesn't use asp .net a long ago and it's answer is for asp .net mvc, not for WebApi. Try to inherit from ApiController and check it.

Comment: @Gusman `WebApi requests don't have access to InputStream anyways as far as I can tell.`

Comment: @Gusman even without any code in the body I get the same result with a WebApi controller.

Comment: WebApi request can access InputStream: `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`

Comment: @Gusman at this point that's irrelevant.  The controller for some reason is not accessible from stripe's testing.

Comment: It works without a problem, I just created a test project and it doesn't fails. I you want I can add the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using WebApi 2 it works with no problem.

Here is the smallest WebApi controller to begin with:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Http;

    namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
    {
        public class StripeController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("api/stripewebhook")]
            public IHttpActionResult Index()
            {
                var json = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                return Ok();
            }
        }
    }
```

if you execute this from VS you can access it from http://localhost:(port)/api/stripewebhook

Now you only need to extend this to include the stripe code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Http;

    namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
    {
        public class StripeController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("api/stripewebhook")]
            public IHttpActionResult Index()
            {
                var json = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

                var stripeEvent = StripeEventUtility.ParseEvent(json);

                switch (stripeEvent.Type)
                {
                    case StripeEvents.ChargeRefunded:  // all of the types available are listed in StripeEvents
                        var stripeCharge = Stripe.Mapper<StripeCharge>.MapFromJson(stripeEvent.Data.Object.ToString());
                        break;
                }

                return Ok();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great answer for WebApi2, the only thing I would mention would be to use StripeEventUtility.ConstructEvent rather than ParseEvent and verify the Stripe-Signature Header as per the official Stripe Documentation.

`var stripeEvent = StripeEventUtility.ConstructEvent(json, HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"],ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Stripe.WebhookSecret"]);`

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#verify-official-libraries